# Android ListView reload data

Tags: android, xml, parsing, listview

Is it possible to reload a ListView once the data is downloaded? Basically I'm updating an app for 4.1 but my ListView downloads and parses an XML file, I know that I have to run this now in a background thread but when I open the activity via a tab the screen is blank. I am not sure how to get this to work or what part of the code I need to use in the background thread, can someone please help. Thank you.

```
    public class ThirdActivity extends ListActivity {

    // All static variables
    static final String URL = "http://selectukradio.com/SelectUKSchedule.xml";     //  http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml  http://selectukradio.com/SelectUKSchedule.xml
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_ITEM = "day"; // parent node   item
    static final String KEY_ID = "link";     //  id
    static final String KEY_NAME = "dj";     // name
    static final String KEY_COST = "time";    // cost
    static final String KEY_DESC = "tempDay";    // description


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_3);


                    try{
                    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
                    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
                    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element


                    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
                    // looping through all item nodes <item>
                    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
                        map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
                        map.put(KEY_COST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST));    // "Rs. " +
                        map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        menuItems.add(map);
                    }

                    // Adding menuItems to ListView
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(ThirdActivity.this, menuItems,
                            R.layout.list_item,
                            new String[] { KEY_NAME, KEY_COST,KEY_DESC,KEY_ID }, new int[] {
                                    R.id.name, R.id.cost, R.id.day, R.id.link });



                    setListAdapter(adapter);

                    // selecting single ListView item
                    ListView lv = getListView();

                    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
                            // getting values from selected ListItem
                            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
                            String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cost)).getText().toString();
                            String link = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.link)).getText().toString();



                            // Starting new intent
                            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
                            in.putExtra(KEY_NAME, name);
                            in.putExtra(KEY_COST, cost);
                            in.putExtra(KEY_ID, link);
                            startActivity(in);

                        }
                    });

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

    }   




    @Override public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {  


        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {             
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            startActivity(intent);
            }     

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
        }
}
```

Comment: listview.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: thanks for the reply but I cant get that to work either, I can solve this by setting minSDK to 8, this is a pain in the back side

Comment: something like that after downloading all data `listview.setAdapter(new YourAdapter())`

Comment: This is the code for the new thread that i found online but i'm really not sure where to implement this code and what part/s of my code go into it    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            //Your code goes here
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});

thread.start();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nick's comment has upvotes but everyone is forgetting that `notifyDataSetChanged()` must be called on the *adapter*, not on the list view.

In this example you are using a `SimpleAdapter` which takes the list of items in the constructor. So to change the data wrapped by the adapter, you have to update this list and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter to get the list view to update.

Here's how you could rework the code to solve your problems. All I have done is move the XML download code to an `AsyncTask`, and moved the list adapter and data items to be instance variables so you can access them when async task completes.

Please note I haven't tested this code, but it should give you the right idea!

```
public class ThirdActivity extends ListActivity {

    // All static variables
    static final String URL = "http://selectukradio.com/SelectUKSchedule.xml";     //  http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml  http://selectukradio.com/SelectUKSchedule.xml
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_ITEM = "day"; // parent node   item
    static final String KEY_ID = "link";     //  id
    static final String KEY_NAME = "dj";     // name
    static final String KEY_COST = "time";    // cost
    static final String KEY_DESC = "tempDay";    // description

    // Initially set list of items to empty array
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mMenuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    SimpleAdapter mAdapter;
    UpdateTask mUpdateTask;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_3);

        // Adding menuItems to ListView
        mAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(ThirdActivity.this, mMenuItems,
                R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { KEY_NAME, KEY_COST,KEY_DESC,KEY_ID },
                new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.cost, R.id.day, R.id.link });
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);

        // selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
                String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cost)).getText().toString();
                String link = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.link)).getText().toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(KEY_NAME, name);
                in.putExtra(KEY_COST, cost);
                in.putExtra(KEY_ID, link);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });

        // Start an update
        updateMenuItems();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {             
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true; // handled event
        }     
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
    }

    // Call this method to download latest XML file from network and update listview
    private void updateMenuItems() {
        if (mUpdateTask == null) {
            mUpdateTask = new UpdateTask();
            mUpdateTask.execute(URL);
        }
    }

    // Async task to download XML on background thread
    private class UpdateTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        // This method runs on a background.
        // Do network operation and returns XML parser, or null on exception
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            try {
                XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
                return parser.getXmlFromUrl(url[0]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

        // This method runs on the main thread when the async task completes.
        // Make sure you only update your UI from this method!
        protected void onPostExecute(String xml) {
            if (xml == null) {
                // Download failed, display error message or something
                return;
            }

            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
            Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);

            // looping through all item nodes <item>
            mMenuItems.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
                map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
                map.put(KEY_COST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST));    // "Rs. " +
                map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                mMenuItems.add(map);
            }

            // all done, notify listview adapter to update
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, I will give this a try and share the results with you.

Comment: This line - mUpdateTask.execute(URL); gives AsyncTask<URL, Void, XMLParser> Cannot be resolved to a type.  Also this line -  private class UpdateTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, XMLParser> gives Multiple markers at this line
 - URL cannot be resolved to a type
 - The type ThirdActivity.UpdateTask must implement the inherited abstract 
  method AsyncTask<URL,Void,XMLParser>.doInBackground(URL...)

Comment: and finally this line - protected XMLParser doInBackground(URL... url) gives Multiple markers at this line
 - implements 
  android.os.AsyncTask<com.pulsarman325.SelectUK.URL,java.lang.Void,com.pulsarman325.SelectUK.XMLParser>.doInBackground
 - URL cannot be resolved to a type.  Sorry if I am missing the obvious

Comment: Oh right, I was using `URL` as a type by accident when it should be `String`. Replace `AsyncTask<URL, Void, XMLParser>` with `AsyncTask<String, Void, XMLParser>`, and `doInBackground(URL... url)` with `doInBackground(String... url)`. I'll update my post.

Comment: Thank you again, there is one more error that I missed on the line Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element. It says xml cannot be resolved to a variable, I can add String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML above it but I guess this defeats the point, do I need one more varible to hold the string xml?

Comment: Hmmm, that's annoying. I guess you can create another parser inside `onPostExecute()` and just return the XML as a String. I'll update my post again.

Comment: It works!!!  I added String xml = new String(); as a varible then changed parser.getXmlFromUrl(url[0]);
to xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(url[0]);  Once again thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final class

```
public class ThirdActivity extends ListActivity {

// All static variables
static final String URL = "http://selectukradio.com/SelectUKSchedule.xml";     //  http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml  http://selectukradio.com/SelectUKSchedule.xml
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_ITEM = "day"; // parent node   item
static final String KEY_ID = "link";     //  id
static final String KEY_NAME = "dj";     // name
static final String KEY_COST = "time";    // cost
static final String KEY_DESC = "tempDay";    // description

String xml = new String();

// Initially set list of items to empty array
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mMenuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
SimpleAdapter mAdapter;
UpdateTask mUpdateTask;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_3);

    // Adding menuItems to ListView
    mAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(ThirdActivity.this, mMenuItems,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] { KEY_NAME, KEY_COST,KEY_DESC,KEY_ID },
            new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.cost, R.id.day, R.id.link });
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);

    // selecting single ListView item
    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
            String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cost)).getText().toString();
            String link = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.link)).getText().toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(KEY_NAME, name);
            in.putExtra(KEY_COST, cost);
            in.putExtra(KEY_ID, link);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });

    // Start an update
    updateMenuItems();
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {             
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true; // handled event
    }     
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
}

// Call this method to download latest XML file from network and update listview
private void updateMenuItems() {
    if (mUpdateTask == null) {
        mUpdateTask = new UpdateTask();
        mUpdateTask.execute(URL);
    }
}

// Async task to download XML on background thread
private class UpdateTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, XMLParser> {

    // This method runs on a background.
    // Do network operation and returns XML parser, or null on exception
    protected XMLParser doInBackground(String... url) {
        try {
            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
            xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(url[0]);
         //   xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
            return parser;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    // This method runs on the main thread when the async task completes.
    // Make sure you only update your UI from this method!
    protected void onPostExecute(XMLParser parser) {
        if (parser == null) {
            // Download failed, display error message or something
            return;
        }

     //   String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);

        // looping through all item nodes <item>
        mMenuItems.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
            map.put(KEY_COST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST));    // "Rs. " +
            map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            mMenuItems.add(map);
        }

        // all done, notify listview adapter to update
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
}
```